# How can I align a background image in a table row in html?

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following code that produces a background image in a table cell.  I would like to put that image in the center of the cell.

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top" width=<%=width%>>
    <div id="loading" 
       style="background-image: url(spinner.gif); height: 16px; width: 16px;">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I tried `align=center` but that didn't work and neither did `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Centering your background image

You're looking for the [`background-position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530718(v=vs.85).aspx) property.

You could also coalesce the properties into the shorter [`background`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property:

```
#loading {
  background: url(spinner.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

#### Centering your element within your cell

One other reading of your question is that you want to center your loading animation in your table cell. If that's the case, I would encourage you to use the CSS properties [`text-align`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`vertical-align`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
td.loading {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

With the following HTML

```
<td class="loading">
  <img src="loader.gif" />
</td>
```

You can see a working demo online at http://jsbin.com/udehox/

it's worth noting that your `DIV` is a block element, and doesn't display `inline` by default. As such, you won't be able to "center" it, since it doesn't permit any space on its left or right.

You can force it to display as an inline element by attaching the `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` statements to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try - background-position: center; that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Ahh, looks like I read the question wrong @Grammin. Jonathan seems to have hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to center the div within the cell.  You can set margins on the div or use relative positioning. Setting a background-position on the image won't help. The div is set to be 16x16 which I'm betting is the size of the image.

Comment: So how do I center the div within the cell?

Comment: Well like I said you can set margins or use positioning CSS. Or follow the second part of Jonathan's answer which is probably the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
 <tr>
 <td valign="top" width=<%=width%>  align="center"  >
 <div id="loading" style="background:url(spinner.gif) no-repeat center center; width:16px;  height:16px;">
</div>
 </td>
 </tr>
```